# Java Swing FileChooser Error

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm following this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

so that i can learn how to use the file chooser in a GUI i am building, but the source file i have downloaded doesn't match up with the tutorial, i am getting an error message whenever i press a button in the GUI.

```
if (e.getSource() == saveButton) {
        FileSaveService fss = null;
        FileContents fileContents = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                (new String("Saved by JWSFileChooserDemo").getBytes()));
                                         //XXX YIKES! If they select an
                                         //XXX existing file, this will
                                         //XXX overwrite that file.

        try {
            fss = (FileSaveService)ServiceManager.
                      lookup("javax.jnlp.FileSaveService"); 
        } catch (UnavailableServiceException exc) { }

        if (fss != null) {
            try {
                fileContents = fss.saveFileDialog(null,
                                                  null,
                                                  is,
                                                  "JWSFileChooserDemo.txt"); 
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                log.append("Save command failed: "
                           + exc.getLocalizedMessage()
                           + newline);
                log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
            }
        }

        if (fileContents != null) {
            try {
                log.append("Saved file: " + fileContents.getName()
                           + "." + newline);
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                log.append("Problem saving file: "
                           + exc.getLocalizedMessage()
                           + newline);
            }
        } else {
            log.append("User canceled save request." + newline);
        }
        log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

I am getting the user cancelled save request.

Comment: the error is "User canceled save request" which is thrown by the program which does run fine, but my issue is that i don't understand why the program is throwing the error instead of working like it should error free.

Comment: Have you tried to specify a file extension like this: `fileContents = fss.saveFileDialog(null, { "txt" }, is, "JWSFileChooserDemo");` ? Also, just for debugging purpose, you should do this to know when `fss` is `null`: `catch (UnavailableServiceException exc) { log.append("Debug: fss is null." + newline); }`

Comment: my guess is that your filecontents is null, your fss two but to be sure change this 
        fileContents = fss.saveFileDialog(null,
                                                  null,
                                                  is,
                                                  "JWSFileChooserDemo.txt"); 
to anything else like system.out.print() to test if your fss is not null

Comment: `catch (UnavailableServiceException exc) { }` bad practise. Are there any exceptions here?

Comment: thanks for replies not really sure what you guys are telling me though

Comment: @almasshaikh no exceptions i think

Comment: @kamino dont really understand what you are tellign me im afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that your `fileContents` may be `null` without you to know it. This can be caused by 2 reasons:

1. The **user cancelled the request**, so `saveFileDialog` returns `null`. This is the message you actually get, but the source of your error can be different ;
2. The error could come from the *extension* parameter of `saveFileDialog` that is `null`...  . If **an exception is raised**, it would be nice to know about it, so I advise you add a message to the log (see code below).

**Solution:**
You should log the `UnavailableServiceException` to keep track of the exception, and you should respect the `saveFileDialog` method prototype (to avoid any ambiguity) as described here: [FileSaveService Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileSaveService.html).

This is the part of your code where are applied the previous advices:

```
try {
  fss = (FileSaveService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.FileSaveService"); 
} catch (UnavailableServiceException exc) {
  log.append("A problem occurred while accessing the service manager." + newline);
}
if (fss != null) {
  try {
    fileContents = fss.saveFileDialog(null, { "txt" }, is, "JWSFileChooserDemo"); 
  }
  /* Your previous code */
}
/* Your previous code */
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, this will at least give your more information about where it comes from.